Asyncio.ws_connect not receiving a connection closure message
async def _connect_session(self):
    websocket_url, headers, cookies = self._get_connect_data()
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
            logger.debug(
                f"Connecting to WebSocket using proxy {self._api.get_proxy().url}"
            )
            async with session.ws_connect(
                websocket_url,
                headers=headers,
                proxy=self._api.get_proxy().url,
                verify_ssl=False,
            ) as connection:
                self.status = True
                self._connection = connection
                self._wait_connect_task.cancel()
                self._matches_controller_task = asyncio.create_task(self._matches_controller())
                logger.debug("Connected to websocket")
                self.ping_task = asyncio.create_task(self._ping(connection))
                await self._listen(connection)
        logger.error(f"WsApp closed {self}")
        self._destruct(WsClosed())
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Exception in WsApp.connect {self}")
        self._destruct(e)


async def _ping(self, connection: ClientWebSocketResponse):
    while True:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(19)
            await connection.send_str("2")
        except Exception as e:
            self._destruct(e)

async def _listen(self, connection: ClientWebSocketResponse):
    while True:
        msg = await connection.receive()
        if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
            data: str = msg.data
            self._message_processor(data)
        elif msg.type in (
            WSMsgType.CLOSE,
            WSMsgType.CLOSED,
            WSMsgType.CLOSING,
            WSMsgType.ERROR,
        ):
            raise WsClosed()

def _destruct(self, err: BaseException):
    self._callbacks.error_callback(self, err)
    if self._run_task is not None:
        self._run_task.cancel()

    if self._matches_controller_task is not None:
        self._matches_controller_task.cancel()


    if self.ping_task is not None:
        self.ping_task.cancel()

`
I have this code and my connection keeps closing when I try to send a message with a ping.
Why doesn't _listen receive a connection close message?
In the logger I only see trace errors from _ping, with no messages or errors from _listen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/adapter/tipsport/tipsport_adapter/pipeline/single_match/data_providers/ws_provider/ws_app.py", line 139, in _ping
    await connection.send_str("2")
  File "/opt/adapter/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 225, in send_str
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=False, compress=compress)
  File "/opt/adapter/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 726, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.TEXT, compress)
  File "/opt/adapter/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 626, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
`


From the error message, the writer is closing before _ping has a chance to write to it.  I can guess what the problem is: In your first function, as soon as the line await self._listen() finishes, the context manager will close the connection.  If that happens before _ping tries to use the writer, you will get this error.
